# Using JavaScript to shrink navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to use [this example](http://www.bootply.com/109943) to add a shrink-on-scroll navbar to a webpage, but when I copied their Javascript and CSS rules across to my document, it no longer worked. The shrink class is not added to my `<nav>` elements like it is on their demo. When I downloaded their demo code, it didn't work either, despite working in the online example.

This is the JavaScript I've used:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
            $('nav').addClass('shrink');
        } else {
            $('nav').removeClass('shrink');
        }
    }); 
});
```

I have also tried using this script with the first (and last) lines removed, as is shown elsewhere in the example.

The only answer I can think of is that Chrome refuses to execute JavaScript on local files. Is this the case, or have I missed something?

Comment: it's more likely that you forgot to include jQuery then an entire chrome bug not executing external files , because everyone else in the world adds external js files just fine

Comment: what console errors are there?  did you include a reference to jquery FIRST then a reference to this js file ?

Comment: @ScottSelby Well spotted. This is the first time I've use JavaScript (hence having to copy-paste a seven line function) and I didn't realise an external thing was needed.

Comment: I put that as an answer - mark as accepted and upvote if that helps and solves your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you include jquery into your html BEFORE your external js file , ex:

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Though seems you have already figured out the problem - just a small suggestion is to try writing your code like this - it will look much better :)

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

    var liveview = $(document).scrollTop();  

    if (liveview > 120) {
        $("nav").addClass("shrink");
    } else {
        $("nav").removeClass("shrink");
    }
});
```

Comment: I think it looks much worse - the reason for setting values in a var usually is to prevent them from being evaluated over and over again , but in this case it doesn't prevent anything , it actually just made the code longer

Comment: I'd prefer to use this method as I can re-use the variable again if I want - which I mostly do. Would save me a couple of characters.